# My javascript bookmarklet does nothing, where did I mess up?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

So I've got this bookmarklet which allows me to quickly switch to the test server version of whatever page I'm on:

```
javascript:(function() {window.location=window.location.toString().replace(/^http:\/\/www\./,'http://www-test.');})()
```

I'd also like to be able to switch to debug mode on my webpages, so I tried making a bookmarklet as below, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
javascript:(function() {window.location=window.location.toString().replace(/^php/,'php?action=debug');})()
```

What did  I screw up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/^php/` only affects a string which starts with `php`. Since the `location.href` property always includes the protocol, your code doesn't do anything.

You might be looking for `/php$/`, which matches php at the end of the string.

To avoid an accidental refresh upon activation of the bookmarklet, you can use:

```
javascript:(function(){
     if(/php$/.test(location.href)) location.href += '?action=debug';
})()
```

Answer (score 1):

`/^php/` matches a string that *starts* with `"php"`. I guess you want to match the *end* of a string:

```
/php$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is the `^` before `php`. Since `php` occurs at the end of the string, you need to anchor it to the right with `$` rather than left:

```
javascript:(function() {window.location=window.location.toString().replace(/php$/,'php?action=debug');})()
```